# Closing app as a process doesn't run a process

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework.  here is my **app.js**

```
.state('app.articlelist,{
   cache:false,
   url:"",
and so on..
)
```

and  controller file

```
.controller('ArticleCtrl',function($scope,getArticle){
  alert("Controller runs");
    getArticle.getAriclefromDb().then(function(res){
      alert("hello test");
   });
});
```

Which is working fine .

Now i have closed my app and also its process.

Now Second time `getArticle.getAriclefromDb().then(function(res){` function doesn't runs.

**but second time i am able to see alert Controller runs** and first time i am able to see both alerts.

Any idea? why this is happening ?

Thanks

Comment: if you get to see the first alert, the second one is definitely running.. However, it may so happen that the second one throws some kinda error or the request is not completed. You should check on that note.

Comment: No, i am not seeing second alter. aster re-opening the app agian

Comment: I don't find any specific reason for that.. May be the second call is failing someway and hence you're not getting the alert.

Comment: even function is not calling.

Comment: the function is getting called but i guess the function in the then part is not executed. Put an alert inside the getAriclefromDb() function and see if you get the alert.